# Django template limit output of the for cycle

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

So I have a template:

```
{% for Chapter in latest_chapter_list %}
                        {% ifequal Chapter.manga|truncatechars:20 Manga.name|truncatechars:20 %}
                            {{Chapter.chapter}}
                        {% endifequal %}
                    {% endfor %}
```

models:

```
class Manga(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,help_text='Name of the comic/manga')

class Chapter(models.Model):
    manga = models.ForeignKey(Manga)
    chapter = models.IntegerField(default=1, help_text='Number of a chapter')
```

So what I want is that the template would only display 5 items instead of all items that pass the if. In normal code I would add a temp value that counts each addition and later on resets, but I'm new to django and I don't know how to approach this.
Also I can't figure out why my if only works if I cut both names to equal length, even though they should be the same length, shouldn't they?

Also my views:

```
def index(request):
    latest_item_list = Manga.objects.all().order_by('-added_on')[:5]
    latest_chapter_list = Chapter.objects.all().order_by('-chapter')



    context = {'latest_item_list': latest_item_list,
               'latest_chapter_list': latest_chapter_list
}
    return render(request, 'Item/index.html', context)
```

any help or tips would be appreciated!

**EDIT, SOLUTION:** made new filtered list in views:

```
latest_chapter_list_short = Chapter.objects.filter(chapter__lt=6)
```

and iterated through it instead of the full list!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django has limited functionality in its templates so it's easier to only iterate over the elements that you wish to display. For example, you can prepare the data in the view to only contain five elements:

```
latest_item_list = Manga.objects.all().order_by('-added_on')[:5]
chapters = Chapter.objects.all().order_by('-chapter')
latest_chapter_per_mange = compute_chapters_per_mange(chapters, latest_item_list)
```

where `compute_chapters_per_mange` determines the chapters per `Manga` model.

Your second question: Django is now comparing the string representation of a `Manga` object to `Manga.name` which may not be the same. This could explain why you need `truncatechars` although I don't fully see why. If you define a `__unicode__` method on your `Manga` model then you can specify how an instance of that model should be displayed as a string (i.e., `self.name`).

Comment: I thought about that, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to compute it properly, and just having limited loop in templates seems like an easier solution, but I see that is not possible.